# SSRS - Add year to month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

In my report, i show the sales commission for 3 months from each sales person. I've also added the payout month. For a better overall look, i want to add the year to the payout month.

This is the month in my SQL-Query :

```
,[Monat] = convert(varchar(4),Year(Datum)) + right('00' + convert(varchar(2),Month(Datum)),2)
```

Right now, the expression for my payout month is this:

```
=MONTHNAME(IIF(RIGHT(Fields!Monat.Value,2)+2>=13,RIGHT(Fields!Monat.Value,2)-12+2,RIGHT(Fields!Monat.Value,2)+2))
```

The payout is always two months in the future. Commission of december 2020 will be payed in february 2021, january 2021 will be payed in march 2021 and so on.

[image]

I want the result to look like this:
Februar 2021,
März 2021
etc.

Is there a way to depict that in the SSRS expression? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you pass a date to SSRS, not a string, you'll find it far easier to manipulate said dates.

Comment: I tried - i have the date fields!datum. But how do i show the year of (date+2months) ?

Comment: Use the `DateAdd` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to display the month and year from a date field after you have added 2 months to it, then you can just do something like this.

```
=DATEADD(DateInterval.Month, 2, Fields!Datum.Value)
```

You can then format the textbox using `MMMM yyyy` to display it as you want.

Alternatively, you can do it all in a single step but this should be avoided if possible as you are then losing the date and converting to a string. If you exported to excel for example, you would not be able to do anything with the cell as it would just be a string.

If you really have to do this in all in a single expression then you can use

```
=FORMAT(DATEADD(DateInterval.Month, 2, Fields!Datum.Value), "MMMM yyyy")
```